Custom metric for Items in GA4
I have an e-commerce site where users can purchase products using credit card (monetary value) or points. For instance, a product that costs $500 can be bought for $300 plus 35,000 points. There are also cases where the product is "purchased" entirely with points. However, in GA4, I want to track revenue only using dollar values. But need the "points" in a different field.
The challenge is that an order event can involve multiple products, each with dollar values and points. Therefore, for each product in the datalayer, I need to send the dollar value (price) and the points value (in a field called "points", for example).
Since GA4 does not allow the creation of custom metrics for items, only for events, is there any solution?
What would be the best solution in this case?
Obs: Sorry for the poor english!

you can create custom dimensions and metric https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/14240153?hl=en
